# Bootstrap List group item wrap around img

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created list group with items but it's only wrapping around text inside it. When I tried span or img it's just not working (Displaying empty item and my image is below). No idea what I'm doing wrong

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ><span class="pull-left "><img src="{{$user->avatar}}"  class="img-reponsive img-rounded"</span>{{$ticket->text}}</li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you never closed the img tag (/>):

```
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" >
           <span class="pull-left ">
             <img src=""  class="img-reponsive img-rounded" />
           </span>
           Text
        </li>
    </ul>
```